# OpenSSL always fails verifying signature generated from Bouncy Castle in Java

Tags: java, openssl, rsa, bouncycastle, sha

I'am trying to generate signatures from files, in order to verify them by clients using OpenSSL, so to implement the corresponding openSSL command in Java using Bouncy Castle :

```
openssl.exe dgst -sha256 -sign privateKey.pem -out \data.txt.sig \data.txt
```

using bouncy castle 1.57 and java, we get bytes array signature from file, which i could verify it in the code. Private, public and certificate are generated from openSSL.

so to generate certificates :

*read the private key from the pem private key file:*

```
PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(PRIVATE_FILE_PATH));
                    PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo encryptedPrivateKeyInfo = (PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo) pemParser.readObject();
JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder jce = new JceOpenSSLPKCS8DecryptorProviderBuilder();
jce.setProvider("BC");
InputDecryptorProvider decProv = jce.build(password.toCharArray());
PrivateKeyInfo info = encryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(decProv);
JcaPEMKeyConverter pemKeyConverter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();
PrivateKey pk = pemKeyConverter.getPrivateKey(info);
```

*and generate the RSA SHA 256 signature and write the result in the signature file:*

```
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(txtFileToSignPath));
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
sig.initSign(pk);
sig.update(data);
byte[] signature = sig.sign();
FileOutputStream dfis = new FileOutputStream(SignaturefilePath);
dfis.write(bytesToWrite);
dfis.close();
```

programmatically i could verify signatures generated  from the code above as well as from open SSL:

```
Signature verifySignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA"); 
byte[] signatureBytes =  
Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(SignaturefilePath);
verifySignature.initVerify(getPublicKeyFromCertFile(CERT_PEM));
verifySignature.update(data);
verifySignature.verify(signatureBytes);
```

on the other hand openSSL is getting always "verification failure" by verifiying signatures generated from code.

is OpenSSL able to verify array of bytes signatures directly, or am I missing anything ?

Comment: I think openssl need the signature to be hex representation of bytes

Comment: encoding the signature array of bytes [] with org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex.encode() doesn't solve the problem :-( still getting verification failure.

Comment: @JEY: no, `openssl dgst -verify` doesn't use hex; in fact since 1.0.2 in 2015 the [man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/dgst.html) has a note (at the end) specifically emphasizing that it doesn't.

Comment: Amine: yes this should work, and does for me. To narrow down, try `openssl rsautl -verify -inkey $certfile -certin -in $sigfile -out $tempfile` and see if you get an error message (and what) or data in the output file (and what); in particular see if the output data looks like an ASN.1/DER DigestInfo for SHA256 and some hash value, and if so compare that hash value to the one for the (asserted) data.

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085, thank you for your response ! in fact it was only an error from my side, i was verifying the signature against another file, the result was correct.I will maintain the question as resolved for learning purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code above works fine, was verifying the signature against another file. Question maitained for learning purpose.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. You can add this info under your question.